# API get permissions from custom groups

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, permissions, rest

I am trying to get the permissions level from groups. Especially for custom groups.

With the following endpoint I get all my groups but cant see permissions

```
_api/web/sitegroups/
```

This endpoint gives me basic roles in SharePoint

```
_api/Web/roledefinitions
```

How can I get the permissions from my custom groups? with JavaScript/jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following endpoint:

```
/_api/web/RoleAssignments/GetByPrincipalId(<principalid>)/RoleDefinitionBindings
```

returns the collection of role definition bindings for the group.

where

- `principalid` - Group Id